# How to use OpenCV in Python with VS as IDE

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, opencv

I have problems getting a project started. I want to work with the library OpenCV in Python, using Visual Studio 2017 as IDE (on windows 10). I added Python extensions (e.g. Anaconda3 64 Bit) to VS via the VS Installer. After that, the struggle begins. Someone told me, Anaconda would be nice to handle multiple packages, so I opened the Python IDE window and set Anaconda as default. Then in the same window I clicked on packages. After executing

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 opencv 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
```

with the text field above the listed packages I was able to see the opencv package in that list. But when I tried to import opencv in a new  python file, it didn't work. (The package was not found)

I also tried to download the latest OpenCV version on the official site, but there I got a folder. I navigated throught this folder and found some .pyd (python extension) files. Can I include them in VS?

I hope anyone can help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use/try/check the `Python Environment Tab` (`View`, `Other Windows`, `Python Environment`) to install stuff to any "environment" you have installed:

[image: python environments]

No idea if it is more comfy or not - I generally use that to install missing dependencies (using pypi - not conda) and the search input to check if it went ok:

[image: searching for a package]

I mostly use the python 3.6 for dev - so not much installed over anaconda defaults.

HTH

Comment: Sorry, my description was bad. I use your method, but opencv ist noch standard package. As I said I used the lines that I wrote down in my qurstion anderen afterwards I could see opencv as a package, but it seemed like I was still not able to use it... (No suggested import)